# Help with a combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics

english is not my first language, so sorry for any typos.
I'm a first year math student, and I'm having problems understanding the meaning of this identity

### $\binom{p+r+1}{q} = \sum_{i=0}^q (\binom{p-i}{q-i}\binom{r+i}{i})$

I tried to formulate a problem using subsets, but i can't visualize the how choosing q objects from p+r+1 would be the same as to what's on the right side. I also tried to formulate one using a grid, but the draw got confusing really fast.
If someone has a combinatorial argument to explain or at least help me understand the meaning of this I would be very thankful.

Comment: Google the hockey stick identity.

Comment: An algebraic proof is quite easy, but you want a combinatorial argument. Right ?

Comment: @RushabhMehta, I did, but if I should use it to prove it (or if they are the same but written differently) I can't see how,
DonaldSplutterwit  yes, I need it using arguments.